# Is it possible to re-register an unregistered Wordpress sidebar?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am customising the Atmosphere Pro theme which is a Genesis child theme. Atmosphere unregisters the sidebar in it's functions.php file.

I could comment out the line that unregisters the sidebar, however, I am trying to avoid touching the theme itself and am instead using a custom plugin to override the theme.

I can't just do `register_sidebar( 'sidebar' );` because otherwise Wordpress treats it as a completely new sidebar.

Is there a way to filter out the `unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar' );` in the functions.php or re-register the unregistered sidebar?

For reference, here is the code in the Atmosphere functions.php file that needs to be overridden:

```
 // Remove sidebars.
 unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar' );
 unregister_sidebar( 'sidebar-alt' );

 // Remove site layouts.
 genesis_unregister_layout( 'content-sidebar' );
 genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-content' );
 genesis_unregister_layout( 'content-sidebar-sidebar' );
 genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-content-sidebar' );
 genesis_unregister_layout( 'sidebar-sidebar-content' );

 // Force full-width-content layout setting.
 add_filter( 'genesis_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' );
```

And the code I have in a plugin:

```
<?php
/*
   Plugin Name: Atmosphere Pro Theme Sidebars
   Plugin URI: https://my.studiopress.com/themes/atmosphere/
   Version: 1.0
   Author: Rose Fisher
   Description: Enables left or right aligned sidebars in the StudioPress Genesis Atmosphere Pro child theme
   Text Domain: atmosphere-pro-theme-sidebars
   License: GPLv3
  */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || die( 'No direct access' );

$theme = wp_get_theme( 'atmosphere-pro' );
if ( $theme->exists() ) { //Check and make sure the theme is set to Atmosphere Pro

    // Add sidebars back - this currently registers a whole new sidebar as sidebar-1
    register_sidebar( 'sidebar' );

    function APTS_get_site_layouts_back() {
     genesis_register_layout( 'content-sidebar', array(
        'label' => __('Content/Sidebar', 'genesis'),
        'img' => get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/lib/admin/images/layouts/cs.gif'
    ) );
        genesis_register_layout( 'sidebar-content', array(
        'label' => __('Sidebar/Content', 'genesis'),
        'img' => get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/lib/admin/images/layouts/sc.gif'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'APTS_get_site_layouts_back' );

    // Force full-width-content layout setting only on front page.
    remove_filter( 'genesis_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' ); //first remove full width

    function APTS_full_width_frontpage() {
        if ( is_front_page() ){
        add_filter( 'genesis_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' ); //then add it back only if it's the front page
        }
    }
    add_action ( 'genesis_meta', 'APTS_full_width_frontpage' );

    // Add back the sidebar CSS after the Atmosphere CSS (based on the Parallax Pro sidebar CSS)
    function APTS_add_sidebar_css() {
            if ( !is_front_page() ) {
                wp_enqueue_style( 'atmosphere-pro-sidebars', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/sidebars.css', array('atmosphere-pro') );
            }
    }
    add_action('init', 'APTS_add_sidebar_css', 99);

}
```

Reference: https://victorfont.com/enable-sidebars-in-atmosphere-pro/

Comment: yes you can unregister side bar  like  <?php unregister_sidebar( $id ); ?> 

 also read  official site  code reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar

Comment: @AnandChoudhary yes I'm aware, thank you. But I'm not wanting to unregister a sidebar, I'm wanting to RE-register a sidebar that has already been unregistered.

Comment: then again register_sidebar with same name you want to register back – Anand Choudhary 1 min ago   edit

Comment: All [`unregister_sidebar`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_sidebar/) does is remove the sidebar name from the `$wp_registered_sidebars` global variable. Just adding the sidebar name back in to that global will probably re-register it.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. I realised the problem was that I need to explicitly state the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `register_sidebar( 'sidebar' );` alone won't work. The ID of the sidebar must be explicitly stated.

The ID Genesis uses is 'sidebar' so the code is thus (note the `'id' => 'sidebar'`) --

```
// Restore the sidebar
function APTS_register_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar( array( 'name' => __( 'Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ), 'id' => 'sidebar' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'APTS_register_sidebar' );
```

In case it is useful for anyone else, this is the full code used to restore left and right sidebars to the Atmosphere Child theme and can be altered to do the same for other Genesis child themes and other sidebars.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Atmosphere Pro Theme Sidebars
Plugin URI: https://my.studiopress.com/themes/atmosphere/
Version: 1.0
Author: Rose Fisher
Author URI: http://www.bespokehosting.space
Description: Enables left or right aligned sidebars in the StudioPress Genesis Atmosphere Pro theme on the blog archive and blog posts.
Text Domain: atmosphere-pro-theme-sidebars
License: GPLv3

Atmosphere Pro Theme Sidebars is free software: you can redistribute it 
and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as
published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the
License, or any later version.

Atmosphere Pro Theme Sidebars is distributed in the hope that it
will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
See the GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with {Plugin Name}. If not, see {URI to Plugin License}.
*/

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || die( 'No direct access' );

// Check and make sure the theme is set to Atmosphere Pro
$theme = wp_get_theme( 'atmosphere-pro' );
if ( $theme->exists() ) {
    // Restore the sidebar
    function APTS_register_sidebar() {
        register_sidebar( array( 'name' => __( 'Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ), 'id' => 'sidebar' ) );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'APTS_register_sidebar' );

    // Put the site layout picker back to the theme and post editors
    function APTS_get_site_layouts_back() {
        genesis_register_layout( 'content-sidebar', array(
            'label' => __('Content/Sidebar', 'genesis'),
            'img' => get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/lib/admin/images/layouts/cs.gif'
        ) );
        genesis_register_layout( 'sidebar-content', array(
            'label' => __('Sidebar/Content', 'genesis'),
            'img' => get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/lib/admin/images/layouts/sc.gif'
        ) );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'APTS_get_site_layouts_back' );

    // Check if the sidebar is actually being used so we don't unneccessarily create sidebar space
    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) {

        // Remove sidebar from homepage and single pages
        function APTS_remove_sidebar_from_home() {
            if ( is_front_page() || is_page() ) {
                remove_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'genesis_get_sidebar' ); // Remove default Genesis sidebar
            }
        }
        add_action( 'genesis_meta', 'APTS_remove_sidebar_from_home' );

        // Add the CSS for the sidebar (pulled from Parallax Pro) only on the blog archive and posts 
        function APTS_add_sidebar_css() {
            if ( is_single() || is_home() ) {
                wp_enqueue_style( 'atmosphere-pro-sidebars', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'css/sidebars.css', array('atmosphere-pro') );
            }
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'APTS_add_sidebar_css' );

        // Force Genesis full-width-content layout setting only on front page.
        function APTS_full_width_frontpage() {
            remove_filter( 'genesis_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' ); //first remove the filter
            if ( is_front_page() ) {
                add_filter( 'genesis_site_layout', '__genesis_return_full_width_content' ); //then add it back only if it's the front page
            }
        }
        add_action ( 'init', 'APTS_full_width_frontpage' );

    }

}
```